# How do I run Node.js api after certain interval of time?

Tags: android, iphone, node.js, push-notification, cron

> I want to send notification to my android and ios app by using REST
>   API of Node.js?
>
> I know it can be done via chrone method but I don't know how to set up
>   that system so I can send push notification to my app users when ever
>   I want (after certain interval of time).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` method in pure JavaScript

```
setInterval(function () {
    //Call to method which will send notification
    // If you have specific endpoint then call to that endpoint
}, 3000);
```

For `cron` job there is also many `npm` packages are available.

Comment: Android/ios user won't hit this api, then how would I do that

Comment: This will add in server code. and save registration id in db etc using apns/gcm npm to send notification. Everything will handle from server side.
Apns https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm  
GCM https://www.npmjs.com/package/apns

Answer (score 0):

/* You can use node-cron module. The node-cron module is tiny task scheduler in pure JavaScript for node.This module allows you to schedule task in node. */

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('1,2,4,5 * * * *', function() {
  console.log('running every minute 1, 2, 4 and 5);
});
```

/*    Above example will run the callback function every 1,2,4,5 minute. You can also provide range such as 1-3 for every 3 min duration.enter code here */